# Strange error message whatever way I try to aggregate mean in R

Tags: r, aggregate, mean

I am making a model to measure Brand and drivers. I do that by using a survey and factor analysis. To validate the stability of the model I have made a routine to bootstrap the whole survey. THe problem is when I try to aggregate. I have used the package (hmisc) and (doBy). Whatever I have tried it did not work. Now, teh problem is that only mean does not work. Standard devation works, max works etc. but mean produces the same error. 
Again, I am a beginner in R, so please be patient. I have probably failed somewhere.

Here is the code:

```
agg<-summaryBy(t1+t2+t3+t4 ~ Brand, data = BTaggtot, 
     FUN = function(x) { c(m = mean(x), s = sd(x)) } )

##Warning message: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = "") :   invalid factor level, NA generated

##  Brand   t1.m    t1.s    t2.m    t2.s    t3.m    t3.s    t4.m    t4.s
##1 x   NA  0.06916467  NA  0.06445095  NA  0.15462236  NA  0.14408303
##2 y   NA  0.12698044  NA  0.11589796  NA  0.11166112  NA  0.09784066
##3 z   NA  0.27728356  NA  0.31683492  NA  0.28952003  NA  0.25356425
##4 a   NA  0.06464727  NA  0.06261208  NA  0.13125807  NA  0.14010969
##5 b   NA  0.13333295  NA  0.13995869  NA  0.07081607  NA  0.05426994
##6 c   NA  0.17935163  NA  0.15829171  NA  0.17706202  NA  0.16386928
```

The raw data file, which in itself is an aggregate from the bootstrapping data:

```
    BTaggtot <- 
    structure(list(Brand = c("x", "y", "z", "a", 
    "b", "c", "x", "y", "z", "a", 

NA)), .Names = c("Brand", "t1", "t2", "t3", "t4"), row.names = c(NA, 
61L), class = "data.frame") 

BTaggtot$t1 <- as.numeric(as.character(BTaggtot$t1)) 
BTaggtot$t2 <- as.numeric(as.character(BTaggtot$t2)) 
BTaggtot$t3 <- as.numeric(as.character(BTaggtot$t3)) 
BTaggtot$t4 <- as.numeric(as.character(BTaggtot$t4))
```

Output:

```
##Brand t1.m    t1.s    t2.m    t2.s    t3.m    t3.s    t4.m    t4.s
##1 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA      NA  NA  NA
##2 x   0.19568792  0.011451510 0.04804116  0.014245490 0.158772048  0.09756682 -0.08942659 0.09520222
##3 y   0.33358223  0.013269567 -0.05392707 0.014502275 0.048156816 0.06733359  -0.12412978 0.05822441
##4 z   0.14213090  0.057348103 0.21348340  0.081216793 0.247131971 0.06523768  0.15880299  0.07527778
##5 a   0.05697128  0.011903945 -0.06825173 0.010993725 -0.128795343    0.08287723  -0.33948934 0.08403221
##6 b   0.33710639  0.006427330 -0.10283455 0.009699357 0.003772128 0.02699491  0.07900255  0.02691813
##7 c   -0.47443412 0.008258243 0.08995661  0.010455134 -0.041590502    0.11071262  0.23812028  0.10615406
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the data are factors. `sd()` can handle factors, `mean()` cannot. Possible help, depending on your problem, can be when reading the data, use `stringsAsFactors=F` in the read function.

Comment: Sorry tried that when reading the .csv. Thers ia a lot of calculations, so I do not know where to put the expression else, when reading the raw data file. At  least that did not work

Comment: Then try to change the class of t's by as.numeric() before the summaryBy.

Comment: I am sorry for disturbing you, but how would that look in code? (thanks)

Comment: try BTaggtot$t1<-as.numeric(BTaggtot$t1). Do this also for t2 - t4. Then runn the summaryBy.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the problem is most likely that your data is stored as `factor`s. However, using `strinsAsFactors=F` will probably not solve the problem. This is because if there *are* strings in your data, then using `stringsAsFactors=F` will prevent the data from being factors, but in that case they will be stored as `character` which still isnt very useful for calculating a `mean`. So I reckon there are several possible things to check.

Make sure, that your data in `t1`, `t2`, `t3` and `t4` does not contain any strings

If you have missing values, make sure that they are represented by `NA` and no other format

When you read in your data, use `stringsAsFactors=F`

Check if it works now, but use

```
mean(x, na.rm=TRUE)
```

If it still wont work, convert your data column by colum to numeric by

```
df$t1 <- as.numeric(as.character(df$t1))  #and so on, for t2, t3, t4
```

Comment: Strangely enough the latter seemed to work, However, It produced an extra row. Why???? Thanks BTW. This is how it looked.  Brand t1.m t1.s t2.m
1 NA NA NA NA
2 x 0.19568792 0.011451510 0.04804116
3 y 0.33358223 0.013269567 -0.05392707
4 z 0.14213090 0.057348103 0.21348340

Comment: It would be much easier to diagnose the problem if you copied the output of 'dput(youroriginaldata)' and paste it into your question (not in the comments).

Comment: Thanks! Sry, I a new poster in this forum. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem, but what you added is not what i meant. Use the function `dput(df)` where `df` is the name of your original data, before you make the aggreateion step and paste the output in your answer (it will look as if it is not readable, but it can easily be copied into any other R session)

Comment: OK! Irun the dput(BTaggtot) and pasted the result into the window. I did not get the fancy code style even though I indented. Sry. I reckon you can see the output and file characteristcs anyway. BR Malte

Comment: If you look at your data, you easily see that there is one row (#61) which a) doesnt have any entry in `Brand` and 2) contains only NA in all other columns. So that is where your "additional" row comes from.

Comment: Hi, I actually found that out no also after printing the content. I think it is from my bootstrap routine that runs an extra time in the for-loop and then produces empty cells. You helped me with the real problem. Thanks for you help. Sometimes you just get stuck.... No I can go on. ;-)